# Drawing balls from a bag using combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Ok we have a *bag of balls* numbered from $1$ to $6$. I need to calculate :

-How many ways there are to draw $3$ balls at the same time : I found $3^{3}$ because I thought that drawing $3$ balls from a bag of $3$ corresponded to drawing $3$ at once but I don't think so.   [SOLVED]

-How many ways there are to divide the 6 balls into 2 groups of 3 : Didn't find anything here. Maybe $$\binom{6}{3} + \binom{6}{3} $$

Thanks

Comment: for 3rd, you are basically "selecting" 3 balls to draw, so $^6C_3$

Comment: If I draw three balls at once, I've split the six balls into two groups; the three that I picked, and the three that are still in the bag.

Comment: Ok so we suppose that it's not ordered ?

Comment: Formatting tip:  To use italics, click on I in the menu.  To stop using italics, click on I again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first case you tak 3 distinct balls out of 6. It's almost book example for combinations. Thus the ansewer is $\binom{6}{3}$.

The second question ask us almost the same question. Notice, that if you draw 3 balls from the bag, 3 are left in the bag - you've just divided them into 2 groups of 3. There is also one thing to notice - drawing balls $\{1,2,3\}$ makes the same division, as drawing $\{4,5,6\}$. For every possible drawing there will be exactly one different 'dual' drawing that create the same division, so each division is counted twice.

The answer is then:
$\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{3}$

Comment: Nicely explained.